# pivot sub array of data pivottable.js

Tags: pivot-table, pivottable.js

I am using pivottable to create and display dynamic report and I would like to know is there any way to pivot the data in sub array on the json?

Example data:

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // This example is the most basic usage of pivot()

  var data = [
    {
      "accountId": "50000X",
      "productId": 1,
      "name": "PRODUCT A",
      "sku": "SKU-A",
      "fulfillmentSku": "SKU-A",
      "friendlySku": "SKU-A",
      "quantityStart": 19524,
      "quantityEnd": 18523,
      "activity": [
        {
          "eventType": "Assemby",
          "createdOnUtc": "2018-01-26T00:00:00",
          "quantity": -1
        },
        {
          "eventType": "Deduction",
          "createdOnUtc": "2018-01-26T00:00:00",
          "quantity": -1500
        },
        {
          "eventType": "Received",
          "createdOnUtc": "2018-01-26T00:00:00",
          "quantity": 500
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "accountId": "50000X",
      "productId": 97,
      "name": "PRODUCT B",
      "sku": "SKU-B",
      "fulfillmentSku": null,
      "friendlySku": "SKU-B",
      "quantityStart": -22,
      "quantityEnd": 48,
      "activity": [
        {
          "eventType": "Assemby",
          "createdOnUtc": "2018-01-26T00:00:00",
          "quantity": 60
        },
        {
          "eventType": "Received",
          "createdOnUtc": "2018-01-26T00:00:00",
          "quantity": 10
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "accountId": "50000X",
      "productId": 96,
      "name": "PRODUCT C",
      "sku": "SKU-C",
      "fulfillmentSku": null,
      "friendlySku": "SKU-C",
      "quantityStart": 2755,
      "quantityEnd": 2755,
      "activity": []
    },
    {
      "accountId": "50000X",
      "productId": 95,
      "name": "PRODUCT D",
      "sku": "SKU-C",
      "fulfillmentSku": null,
      "friendlySku": "SKU-C",
      "quantityStart": -11,
      "quantityEnd": -6,
      "activity": [
        {
          "eventType": "Assemby",
          "createdOnUtc": "2018-01-26T00:00:00",
          "quantity": 5
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  $(function () {
    $("#output").pivot(data,
      {
        rows: ["productId", "name", "sku", "quantityStart", "quantityEnd"],
        cols: ["activity"]
      }
    );
  });
</script>
```

I would like to pivot the activity data, everything in the activity is grouped and computed.
or do I have to change my json format to get the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

PivotTable.js cannot handle nested arrays like this (see the [documentation here](https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/wiki/Input-Formats) with the note about "scalar values not objects") so you will need to restructure your input.